# WPF XAML Visual Stuidio Intellisense ResourceDictionary dll

Tags: wpf, xaml

Здравствуйте. Не работают подсказки intellisense для стилей, определённые во внешней сборки dll. При этом со стилями можно работать, приложение работает. Получается, что имена стилей нужно знать наизусть, или где-то отдельно записывать. Очень не удобно.
Словарь ресурсов со стилями подключаю в App.xaml примерно так:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources;component/Directory.xaml"/>
```

Как заставить работать intellisense с внешней сборкой?

Visual Studio Community 2017 (2) version 15.6.2

Comment: Я бы тоже хотел знать, живу с этим уже 5 лет

Answer (score 1):

Объяви в App.xaml для всего приложения, тогда подсказки для TargetElement будут работать

<Application.Resources>

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Window.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Page.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/CheckBox.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Button.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/TextBox.xaml" />
        
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    
</Application.Resources>
```